# Autentication in Magento Store by URL Token

Tags: php, magento, authentication, token

I would like to implement a way that a customer not logged into Magento store, click on link of your order in transactional email, visit the store already logged in through a token passed in the URL or something like that.

Is there any way to do this in Magento? 
If not, what would be the steps I would have to be developed to achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would like to say that this is a really unsafe approach.
Mails can be forwarded and you don't know that there is an autologin link in the e-mail you can get in trouble.
But if you insist....
[I wrote here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/11480/146) an example of how you can login as a customer in the frontend by the click of a button from the backend.
My approach is somehow safer because the login token is generated each time you click a button, and the generation happens on the backend...so the risk is minimum.
But what you need is a frontend link that should always work.

The idea is to add a new customer attribute that will hold the token.
When sending the e-mail, if the token is null then you generated it. Otherwise use the one you have.
You create your own controller that will handle the token validation (code also provided in the example). If the code matches the customer token then login.

You can also add extra validation conditions. Like including a hashed string in the url with the customer e-mail and id or what even comes in mind.

But again I have to say it...think twice before implementing this.

Comment: Well I will suggest to follow the Marius idea, but design a separate module for it, where you only allow the access of that particular order detail only after validating the token instead of auto Signing In the customer. If customer requires more detail he can login himself. Don't grant the full access of the account on a link in email.